# ¿Cómo validar dominios de correo electrónico?

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Tengo un sistema (en django) donde el registro usuario es por mail, el tema es que quiero bloquear aquellos dominios que son de mail temporal como @yopmail.com para evitar que usen esos correos para registrarse.
No sé que librería o api puedo usar para comprobar que el mail que ingresen sea de un dominio seguro únicamente como gmail,hotmail,etc.

Comment: Y entonces va a haber un grupo de gente que tenga dominios que no estan en la whitelist y no podran registrarse... Mas alla de eso, si hicieras esa restriccion, los que le pagan a Google para tener un dominio personalizado no podrian registrarse (excepto que puedas averiguar realmente quien es el proveeedor de correo electronico). Ademas, que te indica que el usuario no creo la cuenta de mail desde gmail para registrarse y luego borrar dicha cuenta?

Answer (score 2):

no conosco si hay API o NO, pero lo mas simple es limitar los dominios de registro, si ni facebook o instagran pueden luchar contra email's temporales.
si te va a joder lo van a hacer.

podrias poner una limitante que una ves que el usuario se registre tenga que validar el correo en el tiempo, alli los podrias pillar